# ICollectionView's SourceCollection is null

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a ViewModel with two `ICollectionView`s which are bound as `ItemsSource`s to two different `ListBox`es. Both wrap the same `ObservableCollection`, but with different filters. Everything works fine initially and both ListBoxes appear properly filled.

However when I change an item in the ObservableCollection and modify a property which is relevant for filtering, the ListBoxes don't get updated. In the debugger I found that SourceCollection for both ICollectionVIews is null although my ObservableCollection is still there.

This is how I modify an item making sure that the ICollectionViews are updated by removing and adding the same item:

```
private void UnassignTag(TagViewModel tag)
{
    TrackChangedTagOnCollectionViews(tag, t => t.IsAssigned = false);
}

private void TrackChangedTagOnCollectionViews(TagViewModel tag, Action<TagViewModel> changeTagAction)
{
    _tags.Remove(tag);

    changeTagAction.Invoke(tag);

    _tags.Add(tag);
}
```

The mechanism works in another context where I use the same class.

Also I realized that the problem disappears if I register listeners on the ICollectionViews' CollectionChanged events. I made sure that I create and modify them from the GUI thread and suspect that garbage collection is the problem, but currently I'm stuck... Ideas?

**Update:**

While debugging I realized that the SourceCollections are still there right before I call `ShowDialog()` on the WinForms Form in which my UserControl is hosted. When the dialog is shown they're gone.

I create the ICollectionViews like this:

```
AvailableTags = new CollectionViewSource { Source = _tags }.View;
AssignedTags = new CollectionViewSource { Source = _tags }.View;
```

Here's how I bind one of the two (the other one is pretty similar):

```
<ListBox Grid.Column="0"  ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableTags}" Style="{StaticResource ListBoxStyle}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border Style="{StaticResource ListBoxItemBorderStyle}">
                        <DockPanel>
                            <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" ToolTip="Assign" Style="{StaticResource IconButtonStyle}"
                                            Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.AssignSelectedTagCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type tags:TagsListView}}}"
                                            CommandParameter="{Binding}">
                                <Image Source="..."/>
                            </Button>

                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Style="{StaticResource TagNameTextBlockStyle}"/>
                        </DockPanel>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

I use MvvmLight's `RelayCommand<T>` as `ICommand` implementation in my ViewModel:

```
AssignSelectedTagCommand = new RelayCommand<TagViewModel>(AssignTag);
```

Comment: Please post more code.

Comment: @Sinatr: I doubt this has anything to do with it. INotifyPropertyChanged on the items should make no difference for the filtering (and as I wrote: it works in a different context). I got the remove/add idea [here](http://drwpf.com/blog/2008/10/20/itemscontrol-e-is-for-editable-collection/).

Comment: @Ganesh: Could you be more specific? I'm at loss about which code to post without cluttering the post. The ObservableCollection isn't modified anywhere else. Neither are the ICollectionViews.

Comment: I would like to see more about your binding, where you try to update collection.

Comment: I have the same problem with TabControl with two TabItems. Each item has a own ICollectionView in the same view model. Initially the SourceCollection is filled but after loading the first TabItem the second TabItem's ICollectionView's SourceCollection is null.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I had this issue too, with a similar use-case. When I updated the underlying collection, I would call `Refresh()` on all the filtered views. Sometimes, this would result in a `NullReferenceException` thrown from within `ListCollectionView.PrepareLocalArray()` because `SourceCollection` is null.

The problem is that you shouldn't be binding to the `CollectionView`, but to the `CollectionViewSource.View` property.

Here's how I do it:

```
public class ViewModel {

    // ...

    public ViewModel(ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel> items)
    {
        _source = new CollectionViewSource()
        {
            Source = items,
            IsLiveFilteringRequested = true,
            LiveFilteringProperties = { "FilterProperty" }
        };

        _source.Filter += (src, args) =>
        {
            args.Accepted = ((ItemViewModel) args.Item).FilterProperty == FilterField;
        };
    }

    // ...

    public ICollectionView View
    {
        get { return _source.View; }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Whoa? He is doing exactly the same: new CollectionViewSource { Source = _tags }.View;

Comment: This is not exactly the same. `CollectionViewSource.View` is a property, and the value changes.

Comment: What? I tried your way and it works, but I completely do not understand why... Sorry for downvote, this should be the accepted answer!

Comment: The universe is restricted by our own understanding. ;) I think what happens is that under the hood the object referenced by the `.View` property is mutated, and the `.View` property itself changes. I'm not sure how this interacts with the WPF data binding, but it will certainly impact you if you do `.View.Refresh()`.

Anyway. Glad I was able to help you solve your problem.

Comment: See Chris Cannell's answer and the comment there for a more detailed explanation that seems to pan out.  You don't actually need to get the View from the CollectionViewSource each time.  You just need to make sure the garbage collector does not get its greasy paws on the CollectionViewSource, which this code does by storing a reference in the ViewModel.

Answer (score 17):

The reason for your issue is that the `CollectionViewSource` is getting garbage collected.

You can have this problem if you only keep a reference to the `ICollectionView` and was let the `CollectionViewSource` fall out of scope after I'd gotten the view from it. Keep a reference to the `CollectionViewSource`.