# NullReference Exception in PresentationFramework

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Below is a minimal example, I couldn't possibly reduce it any more than this.

I create a live filtered CollectionView in the ViewModel like this:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows;

namespace AntiBonto.ViewModel
{
    [Serializable]
    public class Person
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Name;
        }

        private int num;
        public int Num
        {
            get { return num; }
            set { num = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
        }
    }

    class ObservableCollection2<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
    {
        public ObservableCollection2() : base() { }
        public ObservableCollection2(T[] t) : base(t) { }
        public void AddRange(IEnumerable<T> collection)
        {
            foreach (var i in collection)
            {
                Items.Add(i);
            }
            OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
        }
    }

    class MainWindow: ViewModelBase
    {
        public MainWindow() { }
        private ObservableCollection2<Person> people = new ObservableCollection2<Person>();
        public ObservableCollection2<Person> People
        {
            get
            {
                return people;
            }
            set
            {
                people = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        public ICollectionView Team
        {
            get
            {
                CollectionViewSource cvs = new CollectionViewSource { Source = People, IsLiveFilteringRequested = true, LiveFilteringProperties = { "Num" } };
                cvs.View.Filter = p => ((Person)p).Num != 11;
                return cvs.View;
            }
        }

        public ICollectionView Ujoncok
        {
            get
            {
                CollectionViewSource cvs = new CollectionViewSource { Source = People, IsLiveFilteringRequested = true, LiveFilteringProperties = { "Num" } };
                cvs.View.Filter = p => ((Person)p).Num == 11;
                return cvs.View;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The GUI has a button that modifies a Person object in the People collection:

```
<Window x:Class="AntiBonto.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:AntiBonto.ViewModel"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="AntiBonto" Width="1024" Height="768">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:MainWindow/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
        <FrameworkElement x:Key="DataContextProxy" DataContext="{Binding}"/> <!-- workaround, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7660967 -->
    </Window.Resources>
    <TabControl>
        <TabItem Header="Tab2">
            <StackPanel>
                <Button Content="Does" Click="Button_Click"/>
                <ContentControl Visibility="Collapsed" Content="{StaticResource DataContextProxy}"/>
                <!-- workaround part 2 -->
                <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Ujoncok}" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Who" ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Team, Source={StaticResource DataContextProxy}, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
            </StackPanel>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Window>
```

I load the data from an XML file like this:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace AntiBonto
{
    [Serializable]
    public class AppData
    {
        public Person[] Persons;
    }
    public partial class MainWindow : System.Windows.Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
        }
        private string filepath = "state.xml";
        private AppData AppData
        {
            get { return new AppData { Persons = viewModel.People.ToArray()}; }
            set { viewModel.People.AddRange(value.Persons);}
        }

        private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AppData));
            if (File.Exists(filepath))
            {
                using (var file = new StreamReader(filepath))
                {
                    AppData = (AppData)xs.Deserialize(file);
                }
            }
        }     

        private ViewModel.MainWindow viewModel { get { return (ViewModel.MainWindow)DataContext; } }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Person p = viewModel.People.First(q => q.Name == "Ferencz Katalin");
            if (p.Num == 11)
                p.Num = 0;
            else
                p.Num= 11;
        }
    }
}
```

and the XML file is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AppData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Persons>
    <Person>
      <Name>Person1</Name>
      <Num>0</Num>
    </Person>
    <Person>
      <Name>Person2</Name>
      <Num>0</Num>
    </Person>
  </Persons>
</AppData>
```

When I click the button once or twice, I get a `NullReference` exception. There is no inner exception. The exception does not arise in my code, but in framework code, so it does not show the source, I cannot find out which object is null and where the exception comes from. I didn't manage to set up "stepping into .NET sources", it still tells me that there is no source available.

Here's a stack trace:

> at System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView.RestoreLiveShaping()  at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate
>   callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)     at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source,
>   Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
>     at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object
>   state)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)  at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)  at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)     at
>   MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(CulturePreservingExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)     at
>   System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()     at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32
>   msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)  at
>   MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam,
>   IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)  at
>   MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)   at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate
>   callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)     at
>   System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source,
>   Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
>     at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority
>   priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32
>   numArgs)  at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32
>   msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)    at
>   MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame
>   frame)    at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
>     at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)  at
>   System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)     at
>   System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)     at
>   System.Windows.Application.Run()  at AntiBonto.App.Main() in
>   D:\Marci\Programozás\AntiBonto\AntiBonto\obj\Debug\App.g.cs:line 0    at
>   System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[]
>   args)     at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)     at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()     at
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)   at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)  at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)  at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)     at
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

Comment: @RenéVogt No, it's not.

Comment: I wouldn't call this a duplicate, simply because it shares the same very generic exception as another question.

Comment: @Joe: It may not be an exact duplicate of the canonical "What is a NullReferenceException...` question, but this question still does exhibit a lack of research, and fails to provide a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem. If the problem can be reproduced only using the third-party library, then the right place to seek help is the author of that library. If the library isn't needed, then a question here might be appropriate, but the question needs to include a reproducible example.

Comment: @Peter Duniho Almost all questions on Stackoverflow fail to provide Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable examples (sometimes it's not possible). This guy did his research, he found the only other bit of info in the internet about this issue (which is my question, which faced the same issues of people saying it was a duplicate). Yes, using an external library isn't ideal, but it doesn't invalidate the question. People don't like the question because it has a simple exception that a lot of new coders face, and jump to conclusions.

Comment: @Joe: _"sometimes it's not possible"_ -- there's no exceptions in the posting guidelines for asking for help debugging a problem when you can't provide a good MCVE. I agree (and already said so) that this isn't a duplicate of the canon NRE question. The point of my comment was to encourage you to look beyond the knee-jerk close vote of those others, and objectively evaluate the question. Even without the knee-jerk, the question fails as a good, useful question for Stack Overflow (as did yours, for the same reason: no good [mcve]).

Comment: @PeterDuniho I added the minimal example.

Comment: I have reopened the question, since this is about a NRE in the .NET BCL (apparently a bug in the ListCollectionView implementation), not in the OP's code. Thus, the solution described in the dupe does not apply.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ICollectionView's SourceCollection is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28435477/icollectionviews-sourcecollection-is-null)

Comment: @StayOnTarget The accepted answer doesn't, but I have to try the other one, it seems promising.

Comment: @marczellm actually I think they are both describing the same underlying issue though explaining it differently. I just had a similar issue as this Q and the other one and that is what worked for me anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have no idea why, but this fixed the bug:

```
public ICollectionView Team
{
    get
    {
        CollectionViewSource cvs = new CollectionViewSource { Source = People, IsLiveFilteringRequested = true, LiveFilteringProperties = { "Num" } };
        cvs.View.Filter = p => ((Person)p).Num != 11;
        cvs.View.CollectionChanged += EmptyEventHandler;
        return cvs.View;
    }
}
private void EmptyEventHandler(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) { }
```

I was trying to debug where the exception happens, and I wanted to set a breakpoint when the collection changes. Subscribing to the event made the exception go away.

Comment: This solution seems related to this comment on a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37166747/object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-in-presentationframework#comment75550113_37171952 : by subscribing to the event you keep a reference to the CollectionViewSource and prevents it from being garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a long time trying to debug System.Windows and got nowhere, you're welcome to try.

In terms of a band-aid workaround that will at least function, [from my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37166747/object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object-in-presentationframework/37171952?noredirect=1#comment62326085_37171952) I found that `new CollectionViewSource` causes the issue, whereas `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView` does not.

You mention there are a two issues with this:

**1) I am modifying the base collection all the time and need my filters to refresh**

You can work around this by using ObservableCollections and listening for editions, then updating your filtered instances.

So for each new time you need a CollectionViewSource, create a new ObservableCollection, and keep track of it, add a listener to the original ObservableCollection and push updates to the CollectionViewSource's version.

Elegant? No. Functional? Yes.

**2) I'm using Live Shaping which is not available with GetDefaultView.**

It's always been available for me using GetDefaultView, can you show where you are creating the view?

One similarity I've noticed is that I'm using an extension of ObservableCollection. Do you have the issue if you just use a standard ObservableCollection?

Comment: I will add my own answer later on. Adding an empty CollectionChanged event handler to each of those CollectionViews fixed the issue, I have no idea why.