# ListCollectionView.Refresh() throws ArgumentOutOfRange exception when GroupStyle implemented

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a `ComboBox` whose `ItemsSource` is a `ListCollectionView` which implements filtering and grouping. If I specify the `GroupStyle` for the `ComboBox` in xaml, any time I first select an item from the list of `ComboBoxItems` will throw me an `ArgumentOutOfRange` exception:

```
"Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index"
at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument argument, ExceptionResource resource)
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.get_Item(Int32 index)
at MS.Internal.Data.CollectionViewGroupInternal.Clear()
at System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView.PrepareShaping()
at System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView.PrepareLocalArray()
at System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView.RefreshOverride()
at System.Windows.Data.CollectionView.RefreshInternal()
at System.Windows.Data.CollectionView.Refresh()
at kcplane.ViewModel.ShipViewModel.set_ComboSearchText(String value)
```

The selection is still valid, however, and the change in selection is recognised (for example, triggering a re-sorting of items in an adjacent `ComboBox`, whose values are dependent on that selection).

If the search function I implemented is used to find the selection, then there are no further problems.

I'm trying to group `ComboBoxItems` and filter them with a custom function. To provide a bit of context for the `ListCollectionView` objects, and to make the code more understandable, the `ComboBox` exposes a selection of ships, and these ships are grouped by their Type (Battleship/Destroyer etc.). Typing into the `ComboBox` triggers a search function which finds for ships based on whether their name contains the search text.

So far, I've found discussions of `ArgumentOutOfRange`/`IndexOutOfRange` exceptions pertaining to `ICollectionView`s in general, but not all pertain to C#, let alone wpf. [This post from social.microsoft.com](https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/827db13e-a445-46c1-99f4-a518411cff6c/while-sorting-listcollectionview-it-throws-exception-systemargumentoutofrangeexception-index-was?forum=Offtopic) seems to be the most similar, although pertaining to sorting. But it boils down to the same error (`ListCollectionView` tries to `PrepareShaping()`, and fails). In that case, the problem, I think, was trying to sort the items from another thread while changing the source collection also. Here all I'm doing is to apply a filter and add a group description, so I belive that Windows should be able to handle both at once when `Refresh()` is called to refresh the `ListCollectionView`.

**XAML** (ShipView.xaml)

```
<ComboBox Name="ShipCombo" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,0,2"
          VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
          HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
          ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableShipsCV}"
          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
          IsEditable="True"
          StaysOpenOnEdit="True"
          IsTextSearchEnabled="False" 
          Text="{Binding ComboSearchText, Mode=TwoWay}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name">
    <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>

    <!-- If the section below is taken out, no errors will appear -->
    <ComboBox.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
        </GroupStyle>
    </ComboBox.GroupStyle>
</ComboBox>
```

**ViewModel** (ShipViewModel.cs)

```
public class ShipViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region Fields
    //...

    private string comboSearchText;
    #endregion

    #region Constructors
    public ShipViewModel(List<BaseShip> AvailableShips = null, List<BaseEquipment> AvailableEquipment = null)
    {
        AvailableShipsCV = (ListCollectionView)new CollectionViewSource { Source = AvailableShips }.View;
        AvailableShipsCV.Filter = ShipCollectionViewFilter;
        AvailableShipsCV.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Type")); //There is a property called "Type" in the BaseShip object
        AvailableShipsCV.CurrentChanged += AvailableShipsCV_CurrentChanged;
        //...
    }
    #endregion Constructors

    #region Events
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    #endregion Events

    #region Properties
    public ListCollectionView AvailableShipsCV { get; private set; }

    //...

    public string ComboSearchText
    {
        get
        {
            return comboSearchText;
        }
        set
        {
            comboSearchText = value;

            /////////////////////////////////////
            // This line triggers the error if //
            // GroupStyle is defined in xaml   //
            /////////////////////////////////////
            AvailableShipsCV.Refresh();

            OnPropertyChanged("ComboSearchText");
        }
    }
    #endregion Properties

    #region Methods
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string PropertyName) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));

    // Delegate for filter
    private bool ShipCollectionViewFilter(object item)
    {
        BaseShip ship = item as BaseShip;
        //If the search string is less than three letters long, or if it is empty, then do not filter
        if (ComboSearchText == null || ComboSearchText?.Length < 3) return true;
        return ship.Name.Contains(ComboSearchText);
    }
    #endregion Methods
}
```

**BaseShip Object** (KancolleObjects.cs)

```
public class BaseShip
{
    #region Fields
    //...
    #endregion Fields

    #region Constructors
    public BaseShip()
    {
        //...
    }

    //...

    public BaseShip(string[] entries):this()
    {
        //The name gets stored here, and is never changed
        Name = entries[1];
        //...

        //Same with the type, here.
        ShipType_Short shipType;
        if(!Enum.TryParse(entries[4].Split('/')[1], out ShipType))
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Did not manage to get ship type for ship {Name}.");
            //This message was never output, so no problems here (every BaseShip in the ListCollectionView has a valid type).
        }
    }
    #endregion Constructors

    #region Properties
    //...
    public string Name { get; }
    //...
    public ShipType_Short Type { get; }
    #endregion Properties

    #region Methods
    //...

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
    // Because ItemContainerStyle is set, DisplayMemberPath
    // cannot be set in the xaml. This means we have to rely
    // on the default binding for text, which is ToString()
    #endregion Methods

    #region Constants
    public static BaseShip Empty => new BaseShip();
    #endregion Constants
}

public enum ShipType_Short
{
    //...
}
```

I expect the filtered items to still be sorted according to Type when I search for the item I want, and I do, but not before giving me an `ArgumentOutOfRange`exception which I have to handle.

Answer (score 0):

Probably [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32371238/9758687) will help you. Basically you should use `AvailableShipsCV= CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(AvailableShips);`

Exceptions could occure if the `.View` of the `CollectionViewSource` is used because the reference to `.View` could change.