# Filter / Search binded Listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, observablecollection

Hej,

ive got a ListBox binded to a ObservableCollection and now im trying to Implement a **Search / Filter** Function. But its not working... tried everything :(

Heres a Picture of my ListBox https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuNZS.png

**Ok ive got the Solution thanks to Maximus's Link. Ive Updated my Code.**

and heres what i tried so far my .xaml code

```
 <ListBox Name="lstWarning" Margin="-14,3,-31,-30">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Canvas Height="62" Width="582">
                <Label Foreground="#FFA8A4A4" FontFamily="{DynamicResource HeaderFontFamily}" FontSize="11" Content="{Binding DirName}" Canvas.Left="39" Canvas.Top="23"/>
                <Label Foreground="#FFA8A4A4" FontFamily="{DynamicResource HeaderFontFamily}" FontSize="11" Content="{Binding CreationDate}" Canvas.Left="39" Canvas.Top="40"/>
                <Label Foreground="White" FontFamily="{DynamicResource HeaderFontFamily}" FontSize="14" Content="{Binding FileName}" Canvas.Left="39" Canvas.Top="4"/>
                <Label Foreground="#FFA8A4A4" FontFamily="{DynamicResource HeaderFontFamily}" FontSize="11" Content="{Binding Extension}" Canvas.Left="224" Canvas.Top="40"/>
                <Label Foreground="#FFA8A4A4" FontFamily="{DynamicResource HeaderFontFamily}" FontSize="11" Content="{Binding FileSize}" Canvas.Left="155" Canvas.Top="40"/>
                <Image Source="{Binding StatusImage}" Width="30" Height="30" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="6" Stretch="Fill"/>
            </Canvas>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ListBox>
```

And heres what if done in the TextChanged Event

```
private void cmdSearchWarnings_TextChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.TextChangedEventArgs e) {

        CollectionView cv = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lstWarning.ItemsSource);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSearchWarnings.Text)) {


            if (isFilter) {
                cv.Filter = null;
                isFilter = false;   
            }
            else {
                cv.Filter = new Predicate<object>(FilterByFileName);
                isFilter = true;
            }
        }
        else {
            cv.Filter = null;
            isFilter = false;
        }
    }

    private bool FilterByFileName(object _warningObj) {
        if (_warningList != null) {

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSearchWarnings.Text)) {
                var warning = _warningObj as WarningItem;
                return warning.FileName.Trim().Contains(txtSearchWarnings.Text);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

And heres my WarningItem Class Code:

```
public class WarningItem
{
    public string FullPath { get; set; }

    public string DirName { get; set; }

    public string FileName { get; set; }

    public string FileSize { get; set; }

    public string CreationDate { get; set; }

    public string Extension { get; set; }

    public Uri StatusImage { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Use CollectionViewSource, http://www.wpftutorial.net/dataviews.html

Comment: thanks for the Link but im still confused how to do the filtering maybe somebody could explain it to me

Comment: There is no need to set every time View by calling CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView because it retrieves reference once to object and keeps it throughout life cycle of this object. Do it once in constructor and do not take it from listBox but rather from ObservableCollection. Take a look at my answear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pasting simple example but similar was covered countless time you need to delve in SO. Following sample checks whether collection *Names* containts element which in turn containt searching word.

```
private ObservableCollection<string> _names = new ObservableCollection<string>()
    {
        "Isabel", "Michal"
    };

    public ObservableCollection<string> Names
    {
        get { return _names; }
        set { _names = value; }
    }

    private ICollectionView View;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ListBox.ItemsSource = Names;
        View = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Names);
    }

    private void TextBoxBase_OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        View.Filter = x => x.ToString().ToLower().Contains(((TextBox)sender).Text.ToLower());
    }
```

There is no need to call *CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Names)* in TextBoxChanged event since collectionView is retrieved once and keeps reference. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16634194/wpf-multiple-collectionview-with-different-filters-on-same-collection). 
If it comes to MVVM pattern you are not supposed to use code-behind so instead of

```
<TextBox TextChanged="TextBoxBase_OnTextChanged"/>
```

you are supposed to have

```
  <TextBox Text="{Binding FilterText}">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding FilterListCommand}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </TextBox>
```

[RelayCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn237302.aspx)